# Differentiation while transforming the expression by introducing polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis

The expression that is to be transformed by polar coordinates is $\Big(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\Big)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2$.

So I defined $x=x(r,\phi)=r\cos\phi$ and  $y=y(r,\phi)=r\sin\phi$, where $r>0$ and $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$, and apparently, the derivative of $z$ with respect to $r$ $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$ is equal to $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$, and the similiar goes for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}$.

So my question is how is this so (regarding the derivatives)? Doesn't $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=2\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$? What am I missing?

The solution later on is pretty much straightforward, but I'm absolutely stuck here, and while I believe the answer to my question is fairly simple, I would appreciate if someone would help me as I have shaky basis because I didn't have any classes. Again, apologies if the question is too simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chain rule is correct, we do have

$$ \frac{\partial z}{ \partial r} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}. $$

But derivatives are not fractions, you cannot just cancel the $\partial x$'s and $\partial y$'s to get $2\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$. Derivatives don't work like that. You have to work it through to get

$$ \frac{\partial z}{ \partial r} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \cos \phi+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \sin\phi. $$

The same process yields

$$ \frac{\partial z}{ \partial \phi}= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} (-r\sin \phi)+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} (r\cos\phi).$$

You can then solve for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ and substitute into the expression you want. Hint: I would calculate $\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi}\right)^2$.

Comment: It seems that I framed my question poorly. My question is why is the equation you first typed out true?

Comment: I see. That is the chain rule in 2 variables. I am not going to go into its proof, but you can find a lot of helpful resources if you just google 'chain rule'. Imagine there was no $y$, i.e. $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$. You would get $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}$ which is probably a chain rule you are familiar with.

Comment: Thank you! As I have thought, a fairly simple explanation, but I didn't know where to begin as i didn't have any classes.

Comment: I actually think the chain rule is the most difficult thing in calculus. So don't be too disheartened if it seems complicated.